# Using Ceva's Theorem Proof on Area of a Triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

I am having trouble identifying the height of each triangle.

Comment: Don't use links.

Comment: I do not know how to add pictures without using the link

Comment: @Lily Look at the edit I just made. Or click the picture button when editing the question, and provide the *imgur* link.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: triangles with bases on the same line and a common third vertex have areas proportional to their bases (because they share the same height). Use that to prove that:

$$\frac{AC'}{C'B} = \frac{area(\triangle CAC')}{area(\triangle CC'B)} = \frac{area(\triangle PAC')}{area(\triangle PC'B)}$$

Then note that $area(\triangle CPA) = area(\triangle CAC') - area(\triangle PAC')$, and similar for $\triangle CPB$.

Finally, remember that for equal fractions (with $b \ne d)$:

$$\lambda = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \quad \implies \quad \lambda = \frac{a-c}{b-d}$$

So:

$$\frac{AC'}{C'B} = \frac{area(\triangle CAC') - area(\triangle PAC')}
{area(\triangle CC'B) - area(\triangle PC'B)} = \frac{area(\triangle CPA)}{area(\triangle CPB)}$$

which concludes the proof.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the  area(triangle CPA) because I do not know the height.

Comment: You don't need the heights of $\triangle CPA$, see the new edit.

Comment: So you are saying that triangle CPA and CPB are similar?

Comment: No, I meant that a similar equality holds for $\triangle CPB$ namely that $area(\triangle CPB) = area(\triangle CC'B) - area(\triangle PC'B)$.

Comment: I am still having trouble with this. I know i need to prove some two similar triangles to find the area of triangle CPA and CPB. I still do not know how you got the ratios.

Comment: My professor has indicated to using area formulas to find the area of triangle CPA and CPB.

Comment: And then use similar triangle properties to get the conclusion that those areas are equal to AC'/C'B.

Comment: Could we look at those two right triangles? I think I understand better from there.

Comment: I know those two right triangles are similar by AA

Comment: My answer gives a different solution than what your professor suggested. Next time, if you are looking for some *particular* solution, only, then better indicate that in the body of the question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for trying to help. I will just ask my professor then.